# Styling a JavaFX 2 button using FXML only - How to add an image to a button?

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx-2, fxml, scenebuilder

I want to change the styling of a button, most of the threads here and the articles on the internet show how to do it using Java code, which I don't see it as a real good solution, is there any way for example to set a button with some text and an image inside it all by using FXML only (no Css) ?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

*Solution using only fxml*

As tarrsalah points out, css is the recommended way of doing this, though you can also do it in fxml if you prefer:

```
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.paint.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
  <children>
    <Button layoutX="104.0" layoutY="81.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Love&#10;Potion">
      <font>
        <Font size="30.0" />
      </font>
      <graphic>
        <ImageView fitHeight="150.0" fitWidth="200.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
          <image>
            <Image url="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/mirella-gabriele/fantasy-mediaeval/128/Poison-red-icon.png" />
          </image>
        </ImageView>
      </graphic>
    </Button>
  </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

To get the above in [SceneBuilder](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/tools/index.html), drag an `ImageView` on top of a `Button` and it will automatically be set as a graphic for the button.  Then select the `ImageView` and type the url of the image into the ImageView's image field in the SceneBuilder properties pane.

Open the above fxml in SceneBuilder to see the image below.

[image: lovepotion]

---

*Alternate css attributes*

Alternate css to the `-fx-background*` attributes.

- `-fx-graphic`
- `-fx-padding`
- `-fx-content-display`
- `-fx-graphic-text-gap`

These are just different, not necessarily better for what you are trying to do.  It is just a preference thing as to which to use.  I find these settings easier to use than the `-fx-background*` settings.  They are more restrictive, but the syntax and options are much easier for me to understand and their meanings map to the JavaDoc API for [Labeled](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/Labeled.html#graphicProperty).

A detailed description of the attributes is in the [css reference guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html).

Here's a example with a style setting the graphic embedded in the fxml, though it is always better to separate the style information out into a separate css stylesheet as in tarrsalah's sample.

```
<Button layoutX="138.0" layoutY="226.0" mnemonicParsing="false" style="-fx-graphic: url('http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/mirella-gabriele/fantasy-mediaeval/128/Poison-red-icon.png')" text="Love&#10;Potion">
  <font>
    <Font size="20.0" />
  </font>
</Button>
```

---

*Related solutions for adding images to buttons using only Java code*

- [JavaFX - create custom button with image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10518458/javafx-create-custom-button-with-image)
- [Add image to a button at a specific position JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12678197/add-image-to-a-button-at-a-specific-position-javafx)

Comment: @jewelsea what's with all these love buttons you use in your examples? :)

Comment: @BarbaraKwarc gotta share the love :-)  "Thousands of candles can be lighted from a single candle, and the life of the single candle will not be shortened. Happiness never decreases by being shared."

Comment: @jewelsea what an odd place to discovery these beautiful lines. :)

Answer (score 11):

[FXML](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/fxml_get_started/jfxpub-fxml_get_started.htm) is used just for designing the layout, for styling you can use [css](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html) and reference it from your `FXML` file :

```
 <stylesheets>
    <URL value="@main.css" />
  </stylesheets>
```

To add an image to a `fx:id="btn"` button in your `css`:

```
#btn {          
    -fx-background-image: url("Add.png");
    -fx-background-size: 18 18;
    -fx-background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -fx-background-position:left;   
}
```

This [Github repository](https://github.com/tarrsalah/redButtonFX) provide a complete running example:

[image]

Comment: Where would Add.png be located?

Comment: @AndrewS It would be in the same directory as the CSS

Answer (score 3):

A couple of changes I made to the css example (ref. #btn { in comment #3):

```
-fx-background-size: 100% 100%;
-fx-background-color: transparent;
```

This removed the button outline and left only the image. I was able to resize the button selector in the Scene Builder like an ImageView and see the picture change in realtime. I added a ToolTip to explain the image since there was no text and no button outline. I plan to use techniques explained elsewhere and alter the image when clicked to give more visual feedback that the image is a button.

Also note: I needed to specify the button id in the 'CSS Id' (Scene Builder) instead of the 'fx:id' to get them to be linked.

Adding these changes to what was explained above allowed me to accomplish my goal: have a button that looks only like the image (e.g. round shape in squarish button).