# How can I set a graphic for a TreeItem in FXML?

Tags: javafx, fxml

I'm trying to configure the root node of my TreeView in FXML:

```
<TreeView fx:id="treeView" prefHeight="-1.0" prefWidth="-1.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
    <TreeItem expanded="false" value="Root" fx:id="rootItem" graphic="/icons/icon_folder.png" />
</TreeView>
```

There is a property called `graphic` which takes a `Node`, and not a `String` as I have supplied above.

How do I give it a node in `FXML` that would represent the image stored in my resource at icons/icon_folder.png?

In Java, I can do the following:

```
final Node iconFolder = new ImageView(
        new Image(TreeArchiveSuite.class.getResourceAsStream("/icons/icon_folder.png"))
);
```

And then I can just set it on the root node:

```
rootItem.setGraphic(iconFolder);
```

However, I would like to be able to do this from FXML only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After finding this **[similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16340269/styling-a-javafx-2-button-using-fxml-only-how-to-add-an-image-to-a-button)** about setting the `graphic` property for a `Button` control with FXML, I was able to accomplish my goal with the following FXML markup:

```
<TreeItem expanded="false" value="Root" fx:id="rootItem">
    <graphic>
        <ImageView>
            <image>
                <Image url="icons/icon_folder.png" />
            </image>
        </ImageView>
    </graphic>
</TreeItem>
```