# how to make image buttons on java fxml using scene builder?

Tags: netbeans, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

I am using netbeans and want to use media file from my desktop to replace the boring button.

So this is my code. 
I want it so the image becomes the button.

```
<Button layoutX="252.0" layoutY="177.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="57.0" prefWidth="135.0" text="Button!" textFill="BLUE">
     <font>
        <Font name="Avenir Next Regular" size="13.0" />
     </font>
  </Button>
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16340269/styling-a-javafx-2-button-using-fxml-only-how-to-add-an-image-to-a-button

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your fxml file, import the image package:

```
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
```

then just before the button, assuming image.png is located under "images/" directory and "images/" is located in the same directory as .fxml:

```
<fx:define>
   <Image fx:id="btnImage" url="images/image.png" />
</fx:define>
```

Then just add the following to your button definition

```
<Button layoutX="252.0" layoutY="177.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="57.0" prefWidth="135.0" text="Button!" textFill="BLUE">
     <font>
        <Font name="Avenir Next Regular" size="13.0" />
     </font>

     <graphic>
        <ImageView image="$btnImage" />
     </graphic>
  </Button>
```

Answer (score 15):

The question asks for how to add using scene builder. Here's how..

[image: Screenshot]

Drag imageview from the controls and drop it on top of a button. Note the hierarchy. It should go inside the button. Then you can adjust the size, source and other things within the inspector.

[image: I got this as result]

Got this as result within scene builder

Answer (score 2):

Above answer is partially correct , without specifying the '@' and '$' symbol in url and in "ImageView" like

```
<Image fx:id="playbutImg" url="@image/image.png">
<ImageView image="$playbutImg" >
```

@ symbol is used for diffrentiate between string and relative directory , if we pass without the @ symbol it will take as a string rather than the relative directory.

Answer (score -1):

```
    <fx:define>
            <Image fx:id="NewTracker" url="@resources/NewTracker.bmp"/>
        </fx:define>
        <Button layoutX="100.0" layoutY="100.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="New Tracker" >
                <graphic>
                   <ImageView image="$NewTracker"/>
                </graphic>
        </Button>
```