# JavaFX FXML - Button with icon and text

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I would like to include buttons with icon and text using FXML.

I know that in FXML I can add an image with the following code:

```xml
<ImageView id="boxImage" fitWidth="100" fitHeight="100">
  <image>
    <Image url="@/com/example/app/resources/icons/office.png" />
  </image>            
</ImageView>
```

But I am wondering how to merge that with a button code:

```xml
<Button text="DATE"/>
```

Any help or example is really welcomed as I am totally lost on how to apply an image using FXML.

**Edit**

Following answers I did:

```xml
<Button text="INSTRUMENT" styleClass="">
    <graphic>
        <ImageView pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
            <image>
                <Image url="/com/example/app/resources/icons/instrument.png" />
            </image>
        </ImageView>
    </graphic>
</Button>
```

But I get:

[image]

The button increases its height and therefore is no longer aligned with the other buttons without images.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Styling a JavaFX 2 button using FXML only - How to add an image to a button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16340269/styling-a-javafx-2-button-using-fxml-only-how-to-add-an-image-to-a-button)

Comment: alignment/sizing of children is the task of a layout - choose one that's suitable for your requirements. BTW, you showed what you _don't_ want, better would be to explain what you _do_ want to achieve, best with a [mcve]

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this in fxml

```
<Button layoutX="104.0" layoutY="81.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Love&#10;Potion">
  <font>
    <Font size="30.0" />
  </font>
  <graphic>
    <ImageView fitHeight="150.0" fitWidth="200.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
      <image>
        <Image url="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/mirella-gabriele/fantasy-mediaeval/128/Poison-red-icon.png" />
      </image>
    </ImageView>
  </graphic>
</Button>
```

See the example here [Styling a JavaFX 2 button using FXML only - How to add an image to a button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16340269/styling-a-javafx-2-button-using-fxml-only-how-to-add-an-image-to-a-button)

**UPDATE**:
if you use Java 8

`float width = com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit().getFontLoader().computeStringWidth(btn.getText(), btn.getFont());`

then use the width for the `image`.

Comment: This works but how could I make the image have the same width as text? -see edit-

Comment: beware: don't do any manual sizing/positioning - instead add the buttons into a layout that does it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with css:

```
<Button fx:id="myB" text="DATE" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="150.0" prefWidth="150.0" style="-fx-background-image: url('/img/icons/buttonRed.png');" />
```

Comment: Note a background image is not the same thing as a graphic. However, you can use your approach for a graphic as well via `-fx-graphic: url(...)`.